# CreateView not receiving Kwargs from urls.py

Tags: django, django-views

I've been using arguments provided in the path(...) in urls.py for my view, which is a `TemplateView`.

Now, I've been trying to do the same with a similar template, but using a `CreateView`. After some debugging, I've realized that for some reason a `CreateView` doesn't seem to receive the kwargs defined in the urls.py path. For instance:

urls.py

```
path('product/<int:pk>/', views.SomeViewClass.as_view(), {"foo": "bar"}, name='detail_product', ),
```

views.py

```
class SomeViewClass(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        section = kwargs["foo"]
```

The above works. However, this doesn't:

urls.py

```
path('create/', views.OtherClassView.as_view(), {"foo": "bar"}, name='create'),
```

views.py

```
class OtherClassView(CreateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        section = kwargs["foo"]
```

Any obvious workaround? Other than fishing out this parameter through a completely different pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`.get_context_data(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) indeed does not receive the URL parameters, in that case the `**kwargs` are a dictionary of items that need to be included in the context.

You can work with `self.kwargs` to access the URL parameters:

```
class SomeViewClass(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        section = self.kwargs['foo']
```

Comment: You're right. But then how it worked with the first view? The template view?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions it works with `TemplateView` because that view really doesn't process much, except render a template. In that case it is logical that all kwargs passed to the view would be meant to be rendered in the template, no?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions: because the `TemplateView` is an exception on this rule: it will pass the entire URL parameters as `kwargs` to the `get_context_data`. See: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/#get

Comment: Yes that all makes sense. Alhtough to be honest, from a comparetively newb perspective, I think uniformity would have been nice. Perhaps some ppl appreciate the "shortcut" for the TemplatView I guess...  +1 for the ccbv, didn't know about, I much prefer the way the details are presented there. Easier to use than django docs imo.

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions: yes I agree that it would make sense to pass the URL kwargs always to the context, but of course that is a decision that the architects of Django have to make.